# How do I get all git commits using Jenkins multiple scm plugin with git

Tags: git, jenkins, jira, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

Has anyone successfully setup jenkins multiple scm plugin with git where commits from all configured git repos display in both the git build data and jenkins build job build page?  I've configured all of the git repos with their own name and custom scm name which displays correctly in the middle of the build page but not in the left nav git build data links. Nor do all of the changes from all configured git repos display, only the first one in the list.  Although, all of this information seems to be stored correctly in the build projects build.xml.

Suggestions on a workaround?

In short, I have 5 git repos for one 1 jenkins build project. I would like the commit history for all 5 git repos (not just the top repo) to display or at least be in the git build data link.  This also impacts updating Atlassian's STASH commit's with the jenkins build inforamtion, as well as, JIRA's CI build tab with the Jenkins build information.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install plug-in 'Multiple SCMs plugin' and setup your repositories:

- Repository URL
- Credentials
  **Click on 'Advance' button**
- Name: provide name as 1st repository origin, 2nd origin1 and so on. You can provide any unique name
- Check out to a sub-directory i.e. local subdirectory for repo (directory on your system in which you want your repo to be checked out)
- Custom SCM name

Set up all your repos similar to above steps. Attaching screen shot of my jenkins configuration.

[image: Jenkins configuration with 2 repos]

Comment: Refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003701/how-to-get-change-logs-from-two-repositories-configured-in-jenkins