# How to get change logs from two repositories configured in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

My project uses two repositories. I've configured Jenkins to use two repo[image: Repo configuration in Jenkins]

However, Jenkins is only log changes from one repo. Any idea how can I setup to take changes from both the repo's. I tried Multiple SCM as well however observed the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the "Advanced" Button an insert name "origin" and RefSpec "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
so thats works for me.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. Its working for me since long time forgot to update here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did the same. Its working for me since long time forgot to update here. thanks. 1st repo - Name: Origin, 2nd repo- Name: Origin1
You can leave RefSpec empty it'll work.