# How to get latest on two github repositories in Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins

i trying to get latest on two github repositories in one Jenkins Job as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003701/how-to-get-change-logs-from-two-repositories-configured-in-jenkins)
But i am getting error, what i am missing
[image]

**EDIT1**
I created new JOB and configured two repositories 1st one has name "Origin" and 2nd one has name "Origin2". For both repos i have NOT configured any RefSpec. I see the build is successful now. However workspace has content from the 2nd repo only. The content from 1st repo gets deleted i think. How do i get content from both repos in 2 different folders. Something like workspace/orign and workspace/origin2

Comment: What is the error? Help us out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it
I used https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin and Made sure each SCM checkout is done in a separate sub-directory of the workspace

Example [here](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2015/04/jenkins-how-to-build-project-from.html)